# How do I interpret unmet dependencies error messages?

Tags: installation-profiles

We recently discovered that our clients are running into issues when installing Drupal using our custom default profile. I managed to fix some initial errors like missing libraries, but this other problem stumped me.

> Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException: Configuration objects provided by custom_profile have unmet dependencies: core.entity_form_display.media.document.default (field.field.media.document.field_document, field.field.media.document.field_media_in_library, media.type.document), core.entity_view_display.node.page.default (field.field.node.page.field_content_keywords, field.field.node.page.field_header_image, field.field.node.page.field_header_video_url,
> field.field.node.page.field_hide_overlay_title,
> field.field.node.page.field_meta_tags,
> field.field.node.page.field_secondary_title,
> field.field.node.page.field_social_media_image,
> field.field.node.page.field_title_link,
> field.field.node.page.field_title_placement,
> field.field.node.page.layout_builder__layout,
> metatag),
> filter.format.rich_text_editor_limited (entity_embed), pathauto.pattern.default_media_pattern (pathauto)
> in Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create() (line 100 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/UnmetDependenciesException.php).
> Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create('custom_profile', Array) (Line: 522)
> Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'custom_profile') (Line: 132)
> Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'custom_profile') (Line: 177)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array,) (Line: 83)
> Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array,) (Line: 1660)
> install_install_profile(Array) (Line: 700)
> install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 571)
> install_run_tasks(Array, NULL) (Line: 118)
> install_drupal(Object) (Line: 48)

I searched our code base for the files listed above. The core.entity_* files are located in the /profiles/custom/custom_profile/config/install directory, but the field.field.node.page.* files are all in the /modules/custom/custom_core/config/install directory.

Which of those files does Drupal think are missing, the core.entity.* files or the fields in the parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies in parentheses are the ones the exception is reporting as missing.

Comment: But their yml files are there in the codebase, just in the module directory. Maybe it doesn't know to look for those there?

Comment: I think I’ve answered the question as written. Obviously there are more questions to ask.